# How do I turn off auto disabling of the modem mode when loss of the network?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, wifi, internet-sharing

I use my Lumia 830 with running Windows 10 Mobile as WiFi hotspot. When the phone loses the network for any reason, it turns off the WiFi hotspot mode and I must enable it again myself.

How do I fix it? How can I do so that it does not turn off the hotspot by itself? Or to make auto enable it back when the network appears?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your phone and your computer (W8.1+) using Bluetooth. Once connected, your phone will show up under Wi-Fi connections, and if the hotspot is oof, it will turn on when you press connect.

This requires that your phone is close to the computer when connecting.

You don't need to unlock your phone when you connect.